# Android: Star path will not fill

Tags: android, canvas, path, shapes

I have a class that creates a Star using `Path` this code is as follows:

```
public Star(int x, int y, int size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    rotateSpeed = 1.5f;

    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x, y-size);
    for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        double radius;
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            radius = size;
        else
            radius = size/2.2;
        double angleRad = Math.toRadians(360/10) * i;
        double cosY = y - (Math.cos(angleRad) * radius);
        double tanX = x + (Math.sin(angleRad) * radius);
        path.lineTo((int)tanX, (int)cosY);
        path.moveTo((int)tanX, (int)cosY);
    }
    path.setLastPoint(x, y-size);
}
```

The problem is that it only draws an outline of it and won't actually fill it despite the fact that I explicitly state `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);`

My drawing code is:

```
public void drawObject(Canvas canvas, boolean antialias) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setAntiAlias(antialias);
    p.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawPath(path, p);

    //Outline
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(5);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawPath(path, p);
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Why won't it fill?

Answer (score 0):

Probably "color" in `p.setColor(color);` is transparent. Make sure the color is e.g. `0xffRRGGBB`

Also `path.moveTo((int)tanX, (int)cosY);` is not needed. The preceeding `lineTo()` does the job.